Pricing a custom option in terms of simpler instruments
I have the following custom European Option $F$ on the underlying $S$ whose pay-off at expiry $T$ follows:
$$
 F(T) = \min{[B, \max{[K_1-S(T), S(T)-K_2,0]}]}
$$
where $B$ is a cash position and $0<B<K_1<K_2$
How do I price this option in terms of simpler instruments, i.e. cash positions and vanilla European options, as needed.
What is the simplest way to approach such problems?

Isnt that just a put spread between K1 and K1-B and a call spread between K2 and K2+B?

Yes, I think @river_rat is right on that. A quick sketch shows similar.
